# Definition of imaginary valued function

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the definition of imaginary valued function?

I am little bit confuse in codomain of imaginary valued function. I imagined the definition as f from R^n to R^2 s.t. range of f is in the form (0,y) where y is real no.
Is it right?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the codomain equals $i\mathbb{R}$ where $i\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Then what does iR (where is real no.) Implies ...Element of iR is 1 tuple element or 2 tuple element?

Comment: This is just used to denote the set of complex numbers$$\{ix:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

Comment: I got it now... thank you...sir